# How would i get code from an external URL and execute it in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

I need to create a **NodeJS** script that will auto-update from a script hosted on my VPS. To do this, i need to get code from my VPS and send it to the client, where the client will execute the code as if it was in the client. I don't know how to achieve this...
what i have:

**client:**

```
WebSocket = require('ws')
ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8720');
var getinit_init_key = "jN*&gbhh*&G8ihae8rwgh78g&*G&*G&GFUibg&GB*&GVBWG";
var getINITKey = JSON.stringify({ init: getinit_init_key, userip: 'server',   reason: 'getUpdate' });
ws.on('open', function open() {
    ws.send(getINITKey);
});
ws.on('message', function(data, flags) {
    d = JSON.parse(data)
    d.x();
});
```

**server:**

```
update1 = require('./socks.js') //socks.js is my code
update2 = update1.init
update = JSON.stringify({ x: update2.toString() });
var ws = require("nodejs-websocket");
var server = ws.createServer(function(conn) {
    console.log("Got new connection!");
    conn.on("text", function(data) {
        try {
            conn.sendText(update)
            console.log(JSON.parse(update).x);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log("RECOVERED FROM ERROR: " +error)
        }
    });
    conn.on("close", function(code, reason) {
        console.log('Sent Update to User');
    });
    conn.on("error", function(error) {
        console.log("Recovered from Error");
    });
}).listen(8720);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually put your code as a js file on the external source and in your client side code using the `<script>` tag you can import the code, like how jquery.js can be used from cdn.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

After you import it you can directly use the methods in that js file.

Comment: I am using NodeJS, not an HTML webpage.

Comment: You can put it in require

Comment: I found something useful:

    var http = require('http'), vm = require('vm'), concat = require('concat-stream');

http.get({
    host: 'localhost', 
    port: 80, 
    path: '/foo.js'
  }, 
  function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.pipe(concat({ encoding: 'string' }, function(ret) {
      vm.runInThisContext(ret, '/foo.js');
    }));
    });

But this only execute the code as normal JavaScrpt, not as Node